# Python Unit Testing using Doctest not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, doctest

I have created a python module to generate weather data(Latitude, Longitude, Elevation and other details) by taking particular location as input.

Updated it as per standards and "pycodestyle" package for checking PEP8 standards does not throw any error or warnings.

My Code is given below :

```
def fetch_location_info(input_list, err_file):

    # URL which gives us Latitude, Longitude values
    LatLong_URL = (
     'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address='
     )

    # URL which gives us Elevation values
    Elevation_URL = (
     'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations='
     )

    # Initializing Error Logs with relevant title for writing error records
    err_line_header = "Logging Location Data Errors"
    print(err_line_header, file=err_file)

    # Insert a new line in the error file after the Error Header
    print("\n", file=err_file)

    # Fetch and Extract Location details from google maps
    input_info = []

    for location in input_list:
        temp_info = {'Location': location}
        latlong_response = requests.get(LatLong_URL + location).json()

        if latlong_response.get('results'):
            for latlong_results in latlong_response.get('results'):
                latlong = (
                    latlong_results
                    .get('geometry', '0')
                    .get('location', '0')
                    )

                temp_info['Latitude'] = latlong.get('lat', '0')
                temp_info['Longitude'] = latlong.get('lng', '0')

                elevation_response = requests.get(
                    Elevation_URL
                    + str(temp_info['Latitude'])
                    + ','
                    + str(temp_info['Longitude'])
                    ).json()

                if elevation_response.get('results'):
                    for elevation_results in elevation_response.get('results'):
                        temp_info['Elevation'] = (
                            elevation_results.get('elevation', '0'))

                        input_info.append(temp_info)
                        break
                else:
                    print("Elevation_URL is not fetching values for {}"
                          .format(location),
                          file=err_file
                          )
                break
        else:
            print("LatLong_URL is not fetching values for {}"
                  .format(location),
                  file=err_file
                  )

    print("\n", file=err_file)
    return input_info
```

Now as a next step, I am trying to do Unit Testing using doctest. *I chose to keep the test cases in a separate file. So I created the following **.txt file*** and kept in the same directory as the code.

```
This is a doctest based regression suite for Test_Weather.py
Each '>>' line is run as if in a python shell, and counts as a test.
The next line, if not '>>' is the expected output of the previous line.
If anything doesn't match exactly (including trailing spaces), the test fails.

>>> from Test_Weather import fetch_location_info
>>> fetch_location_info(["Sydney,Australia"], open('data/error_log.txt', 'w'))
print(input_info)
```

As seen above, the expected condition should return the contents of the list / dataframe / variable that is created within the function being tested. For a try I just tried to print the contents of the list but my unit test output throws error like below since the expected value and got value is not matching :

> > PS C:\Users\JKC> python -m doctest testcases.txt
> >     **********************************************************************  File "testcases.txt", line 7, in testcases.txt Failed example:
> >         fetch_location_info(["Sydney,Australia"], open('data/error_log.txt', 'w'))
>
> Expected:
>
> > ```
> > print(input_info)
> > ```
>
> Got:
>
> > ```
> > [{'Location': 'Sydney,Australia', 'Latitude': -33.8688197, 'Longitude': 151. 2092955, 'Elevation': 24.5399284362793}]
> > ```

So here as you can see that the Test Case worked fine but since I am not able to print the contents of the list, it is failing the test case.

**My question is How can I display the contents of list in the expected section of the unit test case ?**

If I am not wrong, do I need to literally mention the output value in the expected section of the unit test case ?

Any inputs will be helpful

Comment: Your test case is expecting the literal text `print(input_info)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @user2357112 Thats where I got struck. I have written the test case to print the contents of input_info list but it is not printing the contents. So how do I print the contents. Any pointers ?

Comment: Please have a look at the contents of Unit Test case file for more clarity. I have updated the question to have more readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the doctest look exactly as if you ran it at the Python REPL:

```
>>> from Test_Weather import fetch_location_info
>>> fetch_location_info(["Sydney,Australia"], open('data/error_log.txt', 'w'))
[{'Location': 'Sydney,Australia', 'Latitude': -33.8688197, 'Longitude': 151.2092955, 'Elevation': 24.5399284362793}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen for your response. So I need to manually capture the output value for the input value that I give in test case and mention the same in the test case. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes.  Basically run your code from the interpreter and capture the result (if it is correct, of course).  Or, if following best practice and writing tests before generating code, manually write how your code should work at the interpreter and what output it generates, then make your code make the test pass.

Comment: Great. Thank you. One more doubt. I am passing date value as one of the inputs to a function. So when I try to mention datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1) as one input value for a function in the unit test case, it is throwing me an error saying "datetime is not defined". It means do I need to include the ">>> import datetime" statement before the function call line in my unit test case ?

Comment: @JKC Yes..exactly what you would have to do to make it work at the interpreter.

Comment: And one more thing. If a function requires a Dataframe as input, how do I mention this in the test case. Any idea on this ?